# retain indentation relative to first line on multiple line copy & paste

Tags: notepad++, indentation, copy-paste, lines-of-code

Sorry if this has been answered already, but nothing's coming in on google or stack's search.

When I copy & paste multiple lines in Notepadd++, all the lines hold their relative indentation, but they don't relative to the first line.

Does anyone know a setting to make the the n+1 lines hold their indentation relative to the first line pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually possible, not without a plugin anyway!

You could use an auto-indentation plugin like the following: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

A quick way to adjust indentation as well is to highlight the whole misaligned section and press **Tab** to move it all to the **right**, and press **Shift + Tab** if you want it all to move to the **left**!